# Introduction of graphtheory and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have A question about this theory:
1.How much graph labeled with n point? 
I get the answer is 2^((n
(n-1))/2)

I"m still confused how to proof it?

and how we can show that in 2^((n(n-1))/2) graph with n points?

And can you help me , and can you
give me a theory with graph labeled

thanks, and i"m very sorry if i can"t write english with perfect :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each edge AB of the graph, there are two labeled graphs associated with this edge: a graph with AB as an edge and another graph with AB a non-edge ( it only has A and B are vertices but AB is not an edge ). So this means for each edge there are 2 labeled graphs. Now for n point graph, there are C(n, 2) = n(n -1)/2 possible edges. So the total number of labeled graphs is : 2^(n(n-1)/2).

Comment: Thanks,
and i want to ask again,how about the related theory?
I'm still confused about it :-D

Comment: any intro to graph theory book will be fine. One is Graph Theory by Russell Merris

Comment: Thank you very much ,sir :-D